# Attach tooltip on mat-tab label

Tags: angular

I have been trying to add tooltip on tabs but can not seem to add it . I am using matTooltip but on hover nothing happens.Have Seen the docs and other questions on stackoverflow but cant seem to pin point the root cause of the issue.

Is there anything i am missing . Thanks in advance.

```
   <mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="toggleUserType($event)">
            <mat-tab label="Users" class="labelHeading" >
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Bounced Users " class="labelHeading" matTooltip="See Pictures">
            </mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-jnyvvj?embed=1&file=app/tooltip-overview-example.html)**

Add `ng-template`:

```
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
    <label  class="labelHeading" matTooltip="See Pictures"matTooltipClass="example-tooltip-red1">Bounced Users  
    </label>
</ng-template>
```

Try like this:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="toggleUserType($event)">
    <mat-tab label="Users" class="labelHeading">
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Bounced Users " class="labelHeading" matTooltip="See Pictures">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <label  class="labelHeading" matTooltip="See Pictures"matTooltipClass="example-tooltip-red1">Bounced Users  </label>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<mat-tab-group color="primary">
     <mat-tab> 
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
           <label matTooltip="see 1st tab"> 
               First
           </label>
        </ng-template>
        <div class="mat-mt-2">
            <h2 class="mat-text-warn">first tab</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit.</p>
        </div>
     </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```