# add tootip in mat-tab if using ng-container

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab, ng-container

I have issues to add tootip in mat-tab if I use ng-container.

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Users" >
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="users"></ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Cars">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="cars"></ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<ng-template #users>
    <div>many users</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #cars>
    <div>many cars</div>
</ng-template>
```

I tried [Attach tooltip on mat-tab label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803252/attach-tooltip-on-mat-tab-label). It is not working. The difference is that here I use `ng-container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out by myself. I have to add an additional `ng-template` above `ng-container`.

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Users" >
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
           <label matTooltip="See users">Users  
           </label>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="users"></ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Cars">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <label matTooltip="See cars">Users  
            </label>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="cars"></ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<ng-template #users>
    <div>many users</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #cars>
    <div>many cars</div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add tooltips to `ng-container`, because it renders as a `comment`. So you need to change `ng-container` to some `div`/`span`, or attach tooltip to the `div` inside your `ng-template`.

Comment: I can attach tooltip to the div inside your ng-template. But the tooltip is not around the tab then.